# Generating HTML format email with google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, html-email

I'm trying to generate an email and keep the HTML format from Google AppsScript.
I succeeded what : an e-mail, that replaces all the mentioned variables by the data I want but in a plain-text email.
The base of the e-mail is in a Google Spreadsheet cell (A1 cell as mentioned in the code).

But the problem is that there are, for example, hypertext links on the e-mail draft, that are removed because of plain-text e-mail generation.

Is there a way to generate a HTML format e-mail with Google AppsScript ? If you have any solutions or methods, I'll be happy to read.

Many thanks for your help.

This is my code :

```
function createEmailDrafts() {
  var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('fileIDToInsertHere').getSheetByName('Sheet 1');
  var templateSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('fileIDToInsertHere').getSheetByName('Sheet 2');
  var data = dataSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var emailTemplate = templateSheet.getRange('A1').getValue(); // Assuming the email template is in cell A1 of 'Sheet 2'

  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) { // Assuming the first row contains headers
    var name = data[i][0];
    var email = data[i][1];
    var companyName = data[i][2];

    var subject = 'test / ' + companyName;
    var body = emailTemplate.replace(/\[NAME OF THE PERSON\]/g, name)
                            .replace(/\[NAME OF THE COMPANY\]/g, companyName)
                            .replace(/\[EMAIL OF THE PERSON\]/g, email);

    // Create email draft
    GmailApp.createDraft(email, subject, body);
  }
}
```

I'm trying to generate with Google AppsScript an HTML format e-mail, but I'm obtaining a plain-text email .

Answer (score 0):

Try below, you need to use the `GmailApp.createDraft` method differently by specifying the email body as HTML content.

```
function createEmailDrafts() {
  var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('fileIDToInsertHere').getSheetByName('Sheet 1');
  var templateSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('fileIDToInsertHere').getSheetByName('Sheet 2');
  var data = dataSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var emailTemplate = templateSheet.getRange('A1').getValue(); // Assuming the email template is in cell A1 of 'Sheet 2'

  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) { // Assuming the first row contains headers
    var name = data[i][0];
    var email = data[i][1];
    var companyName = data[i][2];

    var subject = 'test / ' + companyName;
    // Replace variables in the template with actual values
    var htmlBody = emailTemplate.replace(/\[NAME OF THE PERSON\]/g, name)
                                .replace(/\[NAME OF THE COMPANY\]/g, companyName)
                                .replace(/\[EMAIL OF THE PERSON\]/g, email);

    // Create email draft with HTML content
    GmailApp.createDraft(email, subject, "", {
      htmlBody: htmlBody
    });
  }
}
```